# Function to prompt and check user input

Tags: c++, strings, parsing

I'm trying to make a function that asks for a string input and then validates it. If the answer is not correct, the function asks them again for valid input with a while loop.

In order to validate the string input, I'm using a string array with all the possible answers to the question.

Because I'm using a string array I need to pass it into the function as a pointer.

The problem I'm running into is that to call the function properly currently I have to type this:

```
std::string possibleAnswers[3] = { "0","1","2" };
//find the length of the possibleAnswers array
int length = sizeof(possibleAnswers) / sizeof(possibleAnswers[0]);
//create a pointer that points at the string array
std::string* pointerPossibleAnswers = possibleAnswers;

//call function to validate input
std::string response = checkInput(pointerPossibleAnswers, length);
```

You'll also notice that I used 
`sizeof(possibleAnswers)/sizeof(possibleAnswers[0]` to find the length which I can't call within the function, because the pointer in the function points to an element in the array, not the entire array.
My function implementation is here:

```
std::string checkInput(std::string* pointerPossibleAnswers, int length)
{
    std::string input;
    //input = toLowerCase(input);
    //create a boolean to continue to ask for input
    bool isAsking = true;
    while (isAsking)
    {
        std::getline(std::cin, input);

        //for loop checks against possibleAnswer array
        for(int i = 0; i< length; i++)
        {
            // dereference possibleAnswers pointer to the
            //ith position of the array
            if (input == *pointerPossibleAnswers)
            {
                isAsking = false;
                //stop checking if a possible response is found
                //break from the loop on next iteration
                i = length;
            }
            //make the pointer point to the next spot
            pointerPossibleAnswers++;
        }
        if (isAsking == true)
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid response, please enter a valid response." << std::endl;
            //reset the pointer to point at original memory 
            //location
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                pointerPossibleAnswers--;
            }
        }
    }
    return input;
}
```

I was just wondering if there is an easier way to call the function, which is one or two lines something like:

```
std::string possibleAnswers[3] = { "0","1","2" };
std::string response = checkInput(pointerPossibleAnswers, length);
```

within two lines that's more efficient, because I have noticed that I'm copying and pasting a lot of code each time. I feel like there is a much more efficient way to do this with a class or a vector, given they have some built in methods for calling

Comment: What about using `std::vector` or `std::array` instead of a raw c-style array of `std::string`?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ That's a good suggestion I'll try changing it to a vector so I can stuff more of it into a function

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Use `std::vector<std::string>` instead C-style array for `possibleAnswers` and then pass a reference to the vector into the `checkInput` function.
- If you will use `std::vector` you can use just [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) to check if the input appears in the `possibleAnswers`.
- Consider making `possibleAnswers` constant<sup>1</sup>. It is never change, is not it?
- The `sizeof` operator returns a value of type [`std::size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) but you use `int length` to hold it. You should use `std::size_t` instead of `int` for the loop counters `i` inside the `checkInput` fucntion as well. Note that `int` is not guaranted to be large enough to hold a size of any object type (an array of `std::string` in your case).
- It is a good habit to prefer pre-increment over post-increment all things being equal in C++ since the first usually is [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-i-and-i-in-c).
- Do not comment your code too much. Anyone perfectly knows that `*` means *dereference*:

  > ```
  > // dereference possibleAnswers pointer to the
  > //ith position of the array
  > if (input == *pointerPossibleAnswers)
  > ```

  Make it a rule: "*Comments shouldn't say **what** happens in code, they should say **why** this is happens*".
- You can easily restructure your code to get rid of the `isAsking` flag variable. All you have to do is explicitly return `input` when it equals to one of the possible answer.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> As mentioned @πάντα ῥεῖ in the comments if you'll decide to use to make `possibleAnswers` constant you may want to use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). But in this case you have to use templates to pass different sized arrays to the `possibleAnswers` function.</sub>

Comment: _"It is a good habit to prefer pre-increment over post-increment ..."_ That's a long standing myth still told, while no longer really valid for modern optimizing compilers. I also still prefer pre-incerement though.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, but it is still a good habit, especially if you are forced to use a dinosaur compiler.

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to mention that performance isn't an argument anymore for most modern compilers.

Comment: @eanmos Thanks for the suggestions, I apologise for my inexperience. I think I'll try using templates, given const vectors are a little redundant. I genuinely was not aware of std::size_t nor pre-increment. I'll cut down on the comments as well

Comment: @eanmos one point of clarification, if I get rid of the boolean isAsking I'm just thing that the other option would be to have a while(true) loop which I've always been advised is bad practice, is there another option which would be a little better?

Comment: Also, I was just thinking about how would I use templates to go about implementing this code?

Answer (score 2):

## Include the necessary standard headers

To compile successfully, this code needs at least

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
```

## Don't use signed types for size

Prefer `std::size_t length`.

## Don't compare booleans to `true` or `false`

A boolean that's not `false` must be `true`, so just write

```
    if (isAsking)
```

## Consider using an infinite loop

Return from within the loop when we have a matching answer, instead of having to maintain the `isAsking` variable.  That also enables us to reduce the scope of `input`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions I messed up with the booleans and signed types, just with the infinite loop, I was just wondering if there was a better way to do that other than while(true), because I've always been advised not to do that?

Comment: I'd say that `while (true)` is exactly the right way to implement such a loop; I don't think the advice was particularly good.  You do want to take care that the control flow is understandable, but I don't expect that to be a problem here.